# C#: How to get a resource string from a certain culture

Tags: c#, .net, localization, resources

I have a resource assembly with translated texts in various languages. Project kind of looks like this:

- FooBar.resx
- FooBar.nb-NO.resx
- FooBar.sv-SE.resx
- ...

I can get the texts using static properties like this:

```
var value = FooBar.Hello;
```

Or by using reflection like this:

```
var value = resourceAssembly
      .GetType("Namespace.FooBar")
      .GetProperty("Hello")
      .GetValue(null, null) as string;
```

Both ways will get me the value belonging to the current UI culture of the current thread. Which is fine and totally what I would usually like.

But, is there something I can do if I explicitly want for example the Swedish value, without having to change the UI culture?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can manually change the `Culture` property of the FooBar class that Visual Studio generates. Or if you are directly using the [ResourceManager class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx), you can use the overload of [GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsb0cfet.aspx) that takes the desired culture as a parameter.

Comment: Can ResourceManagers be created and thrown away easily, or do they require clean up and/or should they be only created once and used for much?

Comment: Ended up using ResourceManagers :)

Answer (score 29):

Try the following code. It worked fine for me at least:

```
FooBar.ResourceManager.GetString("Hello", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I've used to grab a resource file by culture name - it's vb.net, but you get the idea.

```
Dim reader As New System.Resources.ResXResourceReader(String.Format(Server.MapPath("/App_GlobalResources/{0}.{1}.resx"), resourceFileName, culture))
```

And if you want to return it as a dictionary:

```
If reader IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim enumerator As System.Collections.IDictionaryEnumerator = reader.GetEnumerator()
    While enumerator.MoveNext
        d.Add(enumerator.Key, enumerator.Value)
    End While
    Return d
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the culture in your resource access class. But this is somewhat unrecommended because it leads to lots of other internationalization problems.

E.g. you would have to:

- Handle all number-formatting with the culture overloads
- Ensure that other libraries you use have a similar mechanism that you have
- In cases where the above is impossible (e.g. BCL) create wrappers for everything that MIGHT be culture specific (and that is a LOT of stuff).

So if at all possible change the current UI culture of the current thread.

Answer (score -1):

Use the second overload of GetValue:-

```
 .GetValue(null, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, null, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"))
```

Comment: Hm... I tried this, but it just seemed to return the same value. Will have to try again...

Comment: I guess it would depend on how the property is implemented, you don't actually show the property implementation.

Comment: That's because I haven't implemented it. It's just the default visual studio generated stuff.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to get it to work, so ended up using ResourceManagers. Really wish I could've just used that GetValue overload though. Oh well...