# WPF use English culture resource even when UICulture is Arabic

Tags: wpf, localization, resources, globalization, cultureinfo

I have been playing around WPF recently and I want to know how to use English culture resources even when the app culture is set to another culture say Arabic.

I have defined two resource files containing the HelloWorld key under a Resources folder.

- *AppResources.resx*  (Has HelloWorld = Hello World!)
- *AppResources.ar.resx* (Has HelloWorld = مرحبا بالعالم)

**HomePage.xaml**

First I have declared the resource file's namespace as res

```xml
 xmlns:res="clr-namespace:Demo.Core.Resources;assembly=Demo.Core"
```

and then used it in the label to show **Hello World!**

```xml
<Label Content="{x:Static res:AppResources.HelloWorld}"/>
```

I have set Arabic as the app culture

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("ar");
Resources.AppResources.Culture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

**I want to show the English Hello World! But it is showing the Arabic hello world (مرحبا بالعالم)**

This is because I have set the CurrentUICulture & AppResources culture to Arabic. Is there any way with these setting, I could get still use the English strings defined in AppResources.resx file as it is in XAML? Basically, I want to ignore the culture setting and want to use the English resource directly in the XAML. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ResourceManager` class to programmatically get a resource in a specified culture:

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(AppResources));
lbl.Content = rm.GetString("HelloWorld", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You could use create a converter that performs the translation for you:

```
public class ResourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly ResourceManager s_rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(AppResources));
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string key = value as string;
        if (key != null)
            return s_rm.GetString(key, culture);

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And use it in your XAML markup like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Source=HelloWorld, 
    Converter={StaticResource ResourceConverter}, 
    ConverterCulture=en-US}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue. But I am searching for a way to directly read the content of the AppResources.resx in file ignoring cultures to use in XAML. Let me wait a bit for alternatives to your answers before marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This thread [C#: How to get a resource string from a certain culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825574/c-how-to-get-a-resource-string-from-a-certain-culture) seems to give an answer to what you're looking for. Basically it boils down to call 
`Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("foo", new CultureInfo("en-US"));`
If you need to use it directly from XAML then write MarkupExtension that, given resource key, returns needed localised strings

```cs
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(string))]
public class EnglishLocExtension : MarkupExtension 
{
  public string Key {get; set;}
  public EnglishLocExtension(string key)
  { 
     Key = key; 
  }
  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider provider) 
  { // your lookup to resources 
  }
}
```

I'd prefer this appoach because it's more consice. Xaml:

```xml
<Label Content={EnglishLoc key}/>
```